# Standardize color within an image

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, image-manipulation

I have a .net application where I need to browse for an image, I would like to standardize the colors in the image to just 6 colors?

Is there a library or process to perform this kind of image manipulation?

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform a process called [Color Quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization). This is essentially a process of picking a set of "appropriate" colors for your palette and then finding how far away from each of those colors each pixel in the image is so you can select the closest match to replace it with.

Microsoft have some details on the process here:
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479306.aspx

That said, just using 6 colors does seem a little mean!

Answer (score 0):

I think the term is saving an image with a specific Colour Pallete. (not 100% sure)

Seaching for this revels this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319061

HTH